# NullPointerException when reading manifest signed webstart jar behind authentication layer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, manifest, java-web-start

I have a java webstart application running in a tomcat web server.
The single jar referenced by the JNLP has been signed.
The entire web-application is behind a basic authentication layer.
Web.xml extract:

```xml
    <security-constraint>
    <display-name> Client (SSL)</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Client (SSL)</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>clientuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

 <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Client Webstart</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

When I run the JNLP, webstart correctly asks me to fill in the username and password, but then crashes with the following null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.addPermissions(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out not to be security related, but actually another part of the web.xml that I didn't post before:

```
    <servlet>
    <description>
        The Client.
    </description>
    <display-name>Client</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GenerateClientJNLPServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.GenerateClientJNLPServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GenerateClientJNLPServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-role>
    <role-name>clientuser</role-name>
</security-role>
....
```

The URL pattern for the servlet had been set to *. Which meant that when the JWS process went to the specific location to download the jar is was redirected back to the servlet, which served an error.html page in its response instead of a jar.

I have now limited the servlet url to:

```
<url-pattern>/LaunchClient/*</url-pattern>
```

while the jar continues to be hosted at /releases/*

Answer (score 0):

Add "all permissions" attribute in your JAR manifest. Refer this url for details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html

Comment: Thanks, but the manifest already has:
    Permissions: all-permissions